# Align two DropdownButtons in persistentFooterButtons of Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I have two Dropdown buttons in persistentFooterButtons of Scaffold. However, both are right aligned and left side of the screen is empty. How can I align these buttons so that both buttons fill half of the screen width?

Thank you,

Comment: Provide your code that you have tried.

Comment: did you find any other possibilities for aligning? I want to align Rows to the right and didn't find a working way.

Comment: No. The accepted answer works ok. It is related to persistentFooterButtons being wrapped in ButtonBar. I opened an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46061

Comment: Did you try to wrap your row in a container? It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warp dropdown buttons with container. Then use:

```
final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

new Container(
      width: screenSize.width / 2,
      \\First dropdown button
)

new Container(
      width: screenSize.width / 2,
      \\Second dropdown button
)
```

You can change 2 from any other value for adjust as you want .

Comment: I had to divide by 2.2 instead of 2 due to overflow. Marked as accepted answer but I couldn't upvote because my reputation is less than 15. Thank you.